# How can i add the serial number to rows in Angular ui gird

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using this for my angular grid

http://ui-grid.info/

and i want to add serial numbers to all rows.

I tried this

```
{name: 'ID', field: '', displayName: 'Row Number', cellTemplate: '<div>{{row.rowIndex + 1}}</div>'},
```

But it keep showing on `1` in the column. Lool like `row.rowIndex` is not giving returning anything.

How can i fix that. Thanks

Comment: That single line of code of yours is fine, [works as expected](http://plnkr.co/edit/VxQSzxi3EnQGCqVy7qEa?p=preview). Is there something else?

Comment: @IlyaLuzyanin yes it does seem to work for *ng-grid*, however the question is about *ui-grid*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was very much on to hacking ui-grid found that interpolation of 'rowRenderIndex' solved for me.

use

```
 <span>{{rowRenderIndex+1}}</span>
```

for serial numbers in ui-grid